# Absolute maximum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I´m trying to find the absolute maximum of $(2N-1)$ partial sum of the Fourier´s series of signum function on $[0,\pi]$, I have:

$S_{2N-1}[f](x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{\frac{sen((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}}$

I also have proved the following integral representation:

$S_{2N-1}[f](x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\frac{sen(2Nt}{sen(t)}dt$

I have showed that the maximums on $[0,\pi]$  of   $S_{2N-1}[f](x)$ are $x=\frac{k \pi}{2N}$ with $k=1,3,5,7,...,(2N-1)$ (k odd) .

How could I conclude that the absolute maximum is $x=\frac{\pi}{2N}$?

Thank your four your time.

Comment: In general, if your function is periodic, you can just think of it restricted to its fundamental domain, which is compact. Now you know that a continuous function on a compact set always assumes its global maximum... so you just have to compare the values of all local maxima that you have found, and find which of these is the global maximum.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is: how could I compare all the local maxima without using a computer? Is there any solution for this?